# Cant make text appear with php/ajax code :(

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

First check this site: [check this first plz](http://juicystudio.com/article/making-ajax-work-with-screen-readers.php#ajaxexample)

hi , Im from mexico and Im auto learning html, css, js and php, for personal purposes.

IM trying to add that code to my testing page, the example is Example 3 — Random Fact Generator (form). When you click the random generaton button, it makes random text appear the problem is..WHERE IS IT COMMING FROM? and xml? php server?...I dont know..I checked in ALL the code and nothing :(, I can add random text with other methods like JS with a case and a random.math but I prefer like that page, any sugestions? thx a lotssss

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your code!

Comment: I'l say the magic word here. **jquery** it'l make life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from : http://juicystudio.com/experiments/ajax/form/fact.php

Go see http://juicystudio.com/experiments/ajax/form/script.js

So it comes from a PHP file. The PHP could be reading a XML file, a CSV file, a database, etc.

Let me know if you still have questions.

Edit:
If you don't want to overwrite the last fact you have to change this from script.js:

```
    if (objCurrent)
            objCurrent.parentNode.replaceChild(objReplacement, objCurrent);
    else
    {
        var objContent = document.getElementById('content');
        objContent.appendChild(objReplacement);
    }
```

To

```
   var objContent = document.getElementById('content');
   objContent.appendChild(objReplacement);
```

Edit 2:
CSV file (test.csv)

```
1,test1
2,test2
3,test3
4,test4
5,test5
```

Here is the PHP adapt from the site you have supplied

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");

$array= array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    array_push($array,$data);
}

if(count($array) > 0){
    $id = rand(0, count($array) -1);
    echo $array[$id][1];
}
?>
```

Comment: so...the the text comes from another php that the javascript code calls...mmm sounds easy, let me try it , thx brooo

Comment: lol IT WORKED..but how can I keep calling random text from the same fact.php or I need more pages or what do i do? –

Comment: You mean you want to show multiple random text on the same page ?

Comment: im testing with this link, http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php#.UJLABWcqdG0

Comment: I called a csv file with php and called the array but is not random :(, its from a excel file

Comment: what code? the one from php, the js? all the code is in the example page in the first post, http://juicystudio.com/article/making-ajax-work-with-screen-readers.php#ajaxexample

Comment: Im just using the same code , I dont have experience to make own, im learning, and its fun lolz

Comment: Ok. I don't really understand want you want or what is the question. I have edit my respond including the way to add new fact instead of replacing the last one.

Comment: lol sorry u miss understood , I dont want the text to appear again , just another random fact to appear , just like the example

Comment: I just want to call a random text from some database, and I edit that DB from external

Comment: I want to replace the fact just like in the example , the problem is how to edit the file or call it from another place

Comment: To a Database or a CSV file ? You gived me a link towards a CSV file solution. MySql I supose ?

Comment: Im using a csv file and using this tutorial, http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-php#.UJLABWcqdG0

but the tutorial displays all the arrays from csv and I just want 1 line...like take 1 arraw and post that link, then again, all at random not all at once

Comment: Ok so from a CSV file. I have update my answer. Using a database would definitively be better.

Comment: so I need to edit the csv exactly as u mentioned? then just copy paste that php code to fact.php?

Comment: ok, I know fact.php is calling an xml, if u press f5 in face.php it will reload a new text, so ..wheres is the xml?

Comment: im almost done, JUst need to know how to call the xml in the fact.php but cant understand the js code

Comment: How do you know they are using a xml file ? There is no way of knowing the name of the file. It is not necessary accessible via a http request. (it could be out of the virtual directory). Why are you always changing between the file type ? You ask to use a CSV file, then a database, then back to CSV and now XML...

Answer (score 0):

It gets the text from http://juicystudio.com/experiments/ajax/form/fact.php

In this section, it opens a connection to that page:

```
if (objXMLRequest)
{
   objXMLRequest.onreadystatechange = processResult;
   objXMLRequest.open('GET', 'fact.php', true);
   objXMLRequest.send(null);
}
```

When the connection's state change event fires, it calls the method `processResult`. That method checks that the `readystate` is 4 (completed) and the status is 200 (OK) and updates the text on the page.

You don't need a database or to read files to make that example page. The easiest way would be to create an array of facts and output one at random, like this:

```
<?php
$facts = array("fact 1", "fact 2", "fact 3", "fact 4", "fact 5", "fact 6");
$random_number = rand(0, count($facts)-1);
echo $facts[$random_number];
?>
```

Comment: lol IT WORKED..but how can I keep calling random text from the same fact.php or I need more pages or what do i do?

Comment: fact.php just has one line, I want to add more so how can I call a data base or add more lines?

Comment: Are you trying to get multiple lines with one call? Or do you just want several lines to show up each time you click the button? Or add one more line without replacing the old one each time you click?

Comment: Just like the example I gave, http://juicystudio.com/experiments/ajax/form/

I just want to make that.

Comment: The easiest way would be to put an array of facts in a php file and print one at random. I'll update my answer.

Comment: anyone knows the command? I know how to make random.math in js, can I use js in php files?

Comment: wow thx tom, I think thats game..its enought this code work wonders, <?php
$facts = array("fact 1", "fact 2", "fact 3", "fact 4", "fact 5", "fact 6");
$random_number = rand(0, count($facts)-1);
echo $facts[$random_number];
?>